# Automating storing App settings in web.config (Refactoring)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

There are a bunch of hardcoded strings in a ASP.NET application.

eg. string constSetting = "XYZ";

There are a LOT of them. Is there a tool/plugin for Visual Studio 2008 to refactor it in such a way that the constant string goes into web.config and the above line gets replaced by the retrieved string from web.config app settings?

Comment: Not an answer, but are you sure that the web.config is the best place for these, rather than, maybe, a resource file, or another external config file.  Your web.config would get very cluttered, and you wouldn't be able to change them on the fly without recycling your app domain.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a resource file instead of the web.config. And for this, Resharper is an amazing tool to do this:

[Resharper 5.1 from Jetbrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)

Here are some detailed informations:

[Move Strings to Resource Files](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/internationalization.html#Move_Strings_to_Resource_Files)

Answer (score 0):

This, again, isn't really an answer to your question as such, but resharper do have a method for pulling strings out to resource files:

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_refactoring.html#Move_String_to_Resource